# How to identify the host which started a runner module through the publish.runner module in salt stack?

Tags: salt-stack

I want to start a runner module on the salt master from a minion using the peer_run configuration option and the publish.runner module. The command from the minion looks like this:

```
#> salt-call publish.runner manage.up
```

This works fine.

I'm now trying to write a module which uses the hostname of the minion which started the runner. I did not find any documentation about that so I ask:

How can I get the hostname, inside the runner module, of the minion which started the runner by publish.runner?

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself by dumping out all variables (pprint.pformat(globals()):

It's in the global __opts__ dict. I use this small function to get it now:

```
def get_caller_hostname():
    return __opts__["id"]
```

Comment: You should mark the answer as acccepted so that the question does not show as unanswered ;)